# How to prove that a certain set exists.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove the following:

> Prove that for any $A\times B$, there exists a set $C$ such that $$y\in C\iff y=\{x\}\times B$$

Imagining that such a set exists is simple enough. However, stating the description of a set in words seems insufficient to prove that it is indded a set. For example, the set of all sets does not exist, although the decription of such a set can be stated in words. Also, I read somewhere that if the description of a set can be given with the help of symolic logic, then the set exists. However, I suppose it would be impossible to prove that the description of the set of all sets cannot be given by symbolic logic.

Thanks

Comment: The way you've written it, the set $C$ has to be the singleton set $\{\{x\}\times B\}$ (whose only element happens to be a set). I suspect that's not what is meant....

Comment: Assuming $x$ is a member of $A$ here, the $C$ you're looking for is a collection of subsets of $A\times B$. What axioms would give you that?

Comment: @Greg does raise a point: I'm reading the righthand side as $\exists x\in A(y=\{x\}\times B)$. Otherwise Greg would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has some ambiguous point. I will prove there is a set 
$$
C=\{\{x\}\times B : x\in A\}.
$$

Let $\phi(A,B,x,y)$ be a formula defined as
$$
\phi(A,B,x,y)\iff (x\in A \to y=\{x\}\times B)\land (\lnot (x\in A) \to y=\varnothing)
$$
then $\phi(x,y,A,B)$ is a first-order formula in ZFC. We will check that
$$\forall A\forall B \forall x\exists ! y \phi(A,B,x,y)$$ 
holds. We know that $x\in A$ or $x\notin A$. If $x\in A$, then $\phi(A,B,x,\{x\}\times B)$ holds. If $\phi(A,B,x,y)$ holds, then by definition of $\phi$ we get $y=\{x\}\times B$. Similarly, you can prove the existence and uniqueness of $y$ if $x\notin A$.

Therefore, by replacement $C=\{y : x\in A \text{ and }\phi(A,B,x,y)\}$ is a set.